# PHP unlink está a fazer delete a tudo

Tags: php, delete

Eu tenho este código:
E eu queria apagar um file com base no endereço para diretório e file que lhe é dado, o problema é que está a apagar tudo apesar do argumento (endereço) que passo só pertencer a um file

DB.php

```
public function deleteFromFolder($path) {
        unlink($path);
}

public function fetchAllRandomImageHighlightsAdmin() {
    $sql = ("SELECT `image_path` FROM `highlight_image`);
    $result = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function fetchAllSeveralWorkAdmin() {
    $sql = ("SELECT `image_path` FROM `several_work_image`);
    $result = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

edit.php (delete random image)

```
            if (isset($_POST['idRandom'])) {
            $id = $_POST['idRandom'];

            foreach ($dataBase->fetchAllRandomImageHighlightsAdmin() as $deleteFile) {
                $dataBase->deleteFromFolder($deleteFile->image_path);
            }

            $dataBase->deleteImageWorkRandom($id);
            header('Location: editLisa.php');
        }
```

edit.php (delete several work image)

```
            if (isset($_POST['idSeveral'])) {

            $id = $_POST['idSeveral'];

            foreach ($dataBase->fetchAllSeveralWorkAdmin() as $deleteFile) {
                $dataBase->deleteFromFolder($deleteFile->image_path);
            }

            $dataBase->deleteImageSeveralWork($id);
            header('Location: editLisa.php');
        }
```

Comment: Fazendo um debug, qual o valor de **$path** que chega pra você em suas funções **deleteFromFolderRandomImage** e **deleteFromFolderRandomImage**?

Comment: São ambos diferentes, acabei de ver, mas não faz delete da database dos dois... Aí tudo bem

Comment: Mas o valor de **$path** que está chegando é realmente o path de um arquivo? Quando você diz que está apagando tudo, você quer dizer que está apagando todo o conteúdo do diretório onde se encontra o arquivo?

Comment: Aliás peço desculpa se fizer um echo dentro do foreach em vez de '$dataBase->deleteFromFolderSeveralWork' nem aparece nada, mas se fizer antes do foreach já aparecem todos os paths relativos à table

Comment: Editei o codigo, simplifiquei um pouco... No entanto os resultados são os mesmos

Comment: Certo, o `echo` que você fez era para apresentar o que? Dentro do `foreach` faça um `echo $deleteSeveralFile->image_path;` e veja o que é retornado. Apenas para verificar se o conteúdo desse atributo é válido e o que você está esperando...

Comment: Não retorna nada, não está sequer a imprimir um 'echo 'hey', no entanto apaga do folder... Não percebo...

Comment: Acho que já sei... o problema é que eu estou a fazer fetch a tudo o que está dentro daquela tabela e apagar cada path, preciso de adicionar um sql que faça select apenas ao path do id selecionado, vou fazer update assim que estiver... Muito obrigado @Adriano

Comment: OK, se conseguir resolver avise por aqui... Ia pedir para você verificar usando `print_r()` o valor de `$dataBase->fetchAllSeveralWorkAdmin()` para verificar se o array está correto com o path das imagens realmente. Mas caso consiga resolver avise... =)

Comment: Miguel, aqui não usamos "resolvido" no título. Por favor, publique uma resposta e marque-a como correta. Confira o [tour] do site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que estava a selecionar todos os elementos de cada tabela e ia apagando um por um. A maneira correta é:

DB.php

```
public function selectRandomImageToDelete($id) {
    $sql = ("SELECT `image_path` FROM `highlight_image` WHERE `id` = $id");
    $result = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function selectSeveralImageToDelete($id) {
    $sql = ("SELECT `image_path` FROM `several_work_image` WHERE `id` = $id");
    $result = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

edit.php (delete random image)

```
if (isset($_POST['idRandom'])) {
            $id = $_POST['idRandom'];

            foreach ($dataBase->selectRandomImageToDelete($id) as $deleteFile) {
                $dataBase->deleteFromFolder($deleteFile->image_path);
            }

            $dataBase->deleteImageWorkRandom($id);
            header('Location: editLisa.php');
        }
```

edit.php (delete several image)

```
if (isset($_POST['idSeveral'])) {

            $id = $_POST['idSeveral'];

            foreach ($dataBase->selectSeveralImageToDelete($id) as $deleteFile) {
                $dataBase->deleteFromFolder($deleteFile->image_path);
            }

            $dataBase->deleteImageSeveralWork($id);
            header('Location: editLisa.php');
        }
```